# Combining/mapping rows in a Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of parking lot names and citation counts, e.g.,

```
Lot_Name                 Citations2019
Brook St Lot Pass A                 50
Brook St Lot Pass B                 46
Brook St Lot Pass C                 76
Campbell                           101
Davidson Pass A                     23
Davidson Pass B                     40
Davidson EXT                        12
...
```

I want to have a new pandas dataframe with some of the above rows combined (e.g., combine all three Brook Street lots and sum their citation counts). How would I be able to do this in Python?

A resulting dataframe would be something like the following

```
Lot_Name              Citations2019
Brook St                        172
Campbell                        101
Davidson                         75
...
```

Comment: Seems like you want [dataframe.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Please show what you've already tried so that we better understand the nature of your difficulty and how best to help. See: creating a [mcve]

Comment: Assuming `Lot_Name` always follows the same pattern & contains the word "Lot", you could try:  `df.groupby(df.Lot_Name.str.split('Lot', n=1).str[0])['Citations2019'].sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Series.str.extract` method to extract the name of the lot, then you can group based on that output:

```
# You can assign this as a column to the dataframe if you want
lot_base = df["Lot_Name"].str.extract("(.+) Lot", expand=False)

print(lot_base)
0    Brook St
1    Brook St
2    Brook St
3    Campbell
4    Davidson
5    Davidson
Name: Lot_Name, dtype: object
```

Regex:`(.+) Lot`: capture all characters until we encounter a " Lot", then stop matching.

Now we can groupby on that Series we just created:

```
# Alternatively within your "groupby" if you assigned lot_base
#  as a column, you can just specify that column's name as a string
out = df.groupby(lot_base).sum()

print(out)
          Citations2019
Lot_Name               
Brook St            172
Campbell            101
Davidson             63
```

Comment: Is there a way to map the data because not all of them follow this format

Comment: You could try extracting the first word via `.str.extract("\w+", expand=False)`. This would return "Brook", "Campbell", "Davidson". But without being able to see more of the edge cases, I can only guess at what will work.